# Using Django Template, how to properly retrieve values that contain brackets in the reference?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

Using Django, I'm trying to retrieve values in my HTML using the object notation, but when I try to parse a reference containing brackets I get the following error:

> Could not parse the remainder: '(occupied=True).count' from 'table.seat_set.filter(occupied=True).count'

Here's the offending HTML code:

```
    <div id="tablelist">
        <p># of Tables: {{ event.table_set.count }}
        {% for table in event.table_set.all %}
        <p>Table {{ table.num }}: {{ table.seat_set.filter(occupied=False).count }} Seats Available</p>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

How do I properly use methods that have () such as filter in my HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do queryset filters in templates. You might want to create a manager which can be called from the template, or create a property on the model for table which can been called.

Example

```
class Table(models.Model):
    #more fields

    @property
    def unoccupied_count(self):
        return self.seat_set.filter(occupied=False).count()
```

and in the templates,

```
{{ table.unoccupied_count }}
```

Comment: I was in the middle of trying to figure out how to create a manager using the examples from the docs, but your solution is a lot more elegant! Thank you!